# Render html in yii2 Gridview Widget

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

That's how I am rendering the values on a grid view

[image]

but instead of links I can see the textual value.

[image]

**How can I make it render html instead of text?**

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In link column configuration add:

```
'format' => 'html',
```

or if you want some extra markup there

```
'format' => 'raw',
```

In case of `raw` remember to encode values coming from outside users because it's not done automatically.

Comment: where are this 'format' configuration documented? i can't find it anywhere. in api doc there is only one example without explanation

Comment: It's mentioned [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-grid-gridview#$formatter-detail) and examples can be found [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/output-formatting).

Answer (score 3):

A better way of doing this in Yii.

```
'value' => function ($data) {
    return Html::a($data->name, [$data->url, 'someData' => $data->someData]);
}
```

Yii Doc: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml#a()-detail

A little late on the post but, hope it helps the in future.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'name',
        'email:email',
        'timestamp:date',
        [
            'attribute'=>'Resume',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'class' => 'yii\grid\DataColumn', // can be omitted, as it is the default
            'value' => function ($data) {
                $url = "www.sample.com/contactform/resumes".$data->resumepath;
                return Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></i>', $url);
            },
        ],

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```