# Yii2: HTML won't be rendered using Tooltip

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, yii2, tooltip

Hint: Pastebin links have been inserted as shown up in my last comment

Hint: Solution of Muhammad still doesn't work(see a picture of the new tooltip)!
[image]

My layout file is coded like this:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use common\wsl_components\AdminLteAsset;

$js = <<<SCRIPT
$(function () {
   $('body').tooltip({
    selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"]',
        html:true
    });
});
SCRIPT;
// Register tooltip/popover initialization javascript
$this->registerJs($js);
AdminLteAsset::register($this);
$this->beginPage()
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?= Yii::$app->language ?>">
    <head>
        <meta charset="<?= Yii::$app->charset ?>"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>
        <title><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></title>
        <?php $this->head(); ?>
    </head>
    <body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini sidebar-collapse">
        <?php $this->beginBody(); ?>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <?=
            $this->render(
                    'header.php'
            );
            ?>
            <?=
            $this->render(
                    'left.php'
            );
            ?>
            <?=
            $this->render(
                    'content.php', ['content' => $content]
            );
            ?>
        </div>

        <?php $this->endBody(); ?>
    </body>
</html>
<?php $this->endPage(); ?>
```

My `GridView` is coded like this:

```
[
    'attribute' => $dummy ,
    'label' => Yii::t ( 'app' , 'Charakterisierung' ) ,
    'format' => 'html' ,
    'value' => function($model) {
        if ( !empty ( $model->person->personentypDominant->typ_name ))  {
            $tag = Html::tag ( 'span' , 'Tooltip-Touch Me!' , [
                   // html-tags won't be rendered in title
                   'title' => $model->person->personentypDominant->typ_empfehlung ,
                   'data-placement' => 'left' ,
                   'data-toggle'=>'tooltip',
                   'style' => 'white-space:pre;border:1px solid red;'
            ] );
            return $tag . "<br>" . $model->person->personentypDominant->typ_verhaltensmerkmal_im_team_1 . "," . $model->person->personentypDominant->typ_verhaltensmerkmal_bei_stress_3 . "," . $model->person->personentypDominant->typ_verhaltensmerkmal_am_arbeitsplatz_4;
        }
    }
],
```

Nevertheless, HTML-Tags in Tooltip won't be rendered. They appear, as they are in database, for instance like this:

```
Verhaltensempfehlung:<br><ul><li>
Kompetenz und Selbstbewusstsein zeigen,</ul></li>
```

I don't know why, but upper tags won't be interpreted. They are in Tooltip hardcoded. Any ideas, what I do wrong?

Edit: My question having been answered by Muhammad is exactly same, but answer didn't solve my problem!
In order to show my problem, look at attachement,please!

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Render html in yii2 Gridview Widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42385274/render-html-in-yii2-gridview-widget)

Comment: can you confirm by adding the normal anchor tag with a tooltip if it displays it properly outside the gridview ?

Comment: I don't undestand. What should I confirm??

Comment: Tooltip nowhere will be displayed properly. Both, in Grid View and in formular, html tags won't be rendered!

Comment: what is the version of bootstrap you are using ?

Comment: try changing the **Register tooltip/popover initialization javascript** line to the following `$this->registerJs($js, \yii\web\view::POS_READY);`

Comment: you can try to  add data-html="true"

Comment: I use Bootstrap beeing involved by "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "~2.0.0", in json. No effect integrating upper registerJS. Including  data-html:true, will cause error:"SyntaxError: missing : after property id" ! Just  html:true, runs without error....

Comment: selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip",html="true",data-html="true"] won't throw out error, any more, but is ineffective!

Comment: can you do one thing can you provide the view-source of that page where it is not working , you can create a pastebin to show the view source ,

Comment: All right: Here is pastebinlink 1:https://pastebin.com/kGSUArfv . And here is pastbinlink 2:https://pastebin.com/8yMryAN6 . Both files don't render html tags correctly!

Comment: Here is pastebinlink for my layoutfile:https://pastebin.com/cYYy6fAn

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have 2 mistakes apparently

1. In this [**`view`**](https://pastebin.com/8yMryAN6) you provided on the line `149` you are missing the attribute `data-toggle="tooltip"` on the spans.

   change them to

   ```
   $tag_rot = Html::tag(
       'span', 'Typ Rot', [
           'title' => $tooltip_rot,
           'data-toggle' => 'tooltip',
           'data-placement' => 'left',
           'style' => 'white-space:pre;border:2px solid red;'
       ]
   );
   $tooltip_green = \common\modules\lookup\models\LPersonentyp::findOne(2)->typ_empfehlung;
   $tag_green = Html::tag(
       'span', 'Typ Grün', [
           'title' => $tooltip_green,
           'data-toggle' => 'tooltip',
           'data-placement' => 'left',
           'style' => 'white-space:pre;border:2px solid green;'
       ]
   );
   $tooltip_blue = \common\modules\lookup\models\LPersonentyp::findOne(3)->typ_empfehlung;
   $tag_blue = Html::tag(
       'span', 'Typ Blau', [
           'title' => $tooltip_blue,
           'data-toggle' => 'tooltip',
           'data-placement' => 'left',
           'style' => 'white-space:pre;border:2px solid blue;'
       ]
   );
   ```
2. In your Gridview column you are using `"format"=>"html"` whereas you should be using `"format"=>"raw"`

   change the column definition to the following

   ```
   [
       'attribute' => $dummy ,
       'label' => Yii::t ( 'app' , 'Charakterisierung' ) ,
       'format' => 'raw' ,
       'value' => function($model) {
           if ( !empty ( $model->person->personentypDominant->typ_name ) ) {
               $tag = Html::tag ( 'span' , 'Tooltip-Touch Me!' , [
                           'title' => $model->person->personentypDominant->typ_empfehlung ,
                           'data-placement' => 'left' ,
                           'data-toggle' => 'tooltip' ,
                           'style' => 'white-space:pre;border:1px solid red;'
               ] );
               return $tag . "<br>" . $model->person->personentypDominant->typ_verhaltensmerkmal_im_team_1 . "," . $model->person->personentypDominant->typ_verhaltensmerkmal_bei_stress_3 . "," . $model->person->personentypDominant->typ_verhaltensmerkmal_am_arbeitsplatz_4;
           }
       }
   ] ,
   ```

The [**`ANSWER`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49085997/yii2-use-htmltag-with-html-content-for-tooltip-bootstrap-3) i gave previously was more focused towards the tooltip usage with the `html::tag()` and i used your code for gridview column to copy paste, and forgot to mention it there in case of using inside the gridview, i have updated that answer too.

Comment: This won't fix my problem. In both cases, html-tags still won't be rendered! I inserted new attachement to show new tooltip above!

Comment: @tklustig, well this works for me you must have something at your end as for gridview format=>raw works perfectly with the tooltip along with the HTML including <br> tags. see here https://imgur.com/a/8RPjMwT

Comment: So I assume, that some CSS-rule of AdminLTE prevents rendering html-tags! I have no idea, of course,which one this colud be. Will U be able to render html-tags using AdminLTE,too??

Comment: For me, tooltip works, too. But only if I render another layout file, without using AdminLTE!! Maybe, error is in layout file as shown above

Comment: if changing the layout is making the tooltip act weird then the only thing i see is `AdminLteAssets` do you have any extra files added inside the asset manager class, can you add it here. @tklustig

Comment: it could be that the custom scripts inside the admin lte are initializing the tooltip ? without `html:true` , could be can you move the script we added on top in the layout for the tooltip to the view where you are initializing the gridview ? can you check that @tklustig

Comment: No change coding like this in GridView after having removed jquery code from layoutfile $js = <<<SCRIPT
$(function () {
   $('body').tooltip({
    selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"]',
    });
});
SCRIPT;

$this->registerJs($js, \yii\web\view::POS_READY);
$this->registerJs($search);
$this->registerJs($checkBox);
common\wsl_components\AdminLteAsset::register($this);

Comment: `app.min.js` is this file actually `adminlte.js` renamed ?

Comment: are you using `jquery.ui` in your application ? @tklustig

Comment: Solved! After having removed app.min.js and copied adminlte.js into js folder and integrated this js-file in my asset-class, html-tags finally will be rendered! Thx for ur efforts helping me! Gave u reputation twice, in both threads! Greetings to Agypt!

Comment: haha turned out some weird javascript is making fun of all programmers `:D` by getting them into a fight on Stackoverflow @tklustig

Answer (score 1):

In case if you still could not achieve a view of HTML inside the tooltip after @Muhammad Omer Aslam's answer.

1. Try to add `'data-html' => 'true'` or with js way `$(selector).tooltip({html: true})` NOTE: based on bootstrap official documentation `Use text if you're worried about XSS attacks.`
2. Check if you do not include a jquery-ui tooltip widget. Which will overwrite bootstrap's tooltip.
   To Fix it add a script like :

```
$(selector).tooltip({
    content: function () {
        return this.getAttribute("title");
    },
});
```

[In this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15734105/jquery-ui-tooltip-does-not-support-html-content) you can find other ways fix jQeuer-UI tooltip

Answer (score 0):

Be warned that Bootstrap 4.3.1 and 3.4.1 now comes with an HTML sanitizer and a most of tags are now suppressed by default.

Here the [bootstrap blog annuncement](https://blog.getbootstrap.com/2019/02/13/bootstrap-4-3-1-and-3-4-1/) and the [docs for 3.4.1](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#js-sanitizer).
So now you need to whitelist any other tag inside your tooltip (or popover) HTML

```
var myDefaultWhiteList = $.fn.tooltip.Constructor.DEFAULTS.whiteList

// To allow table elements
myDefaultWhiteList.table = []

// To allow td elements and data-option attributes on td elements
myDefaultWhiteList.td = ['data-option']

// You can push your custom regex to validate your attributes.
// Be careful about your regular expressions being too lax
var myCustomRegex = /^data-my-app-[\w-]+/
myDefaultWhiteList['*'].push(myCustomRegex)

// initialize your tooltip
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
        // set your custom whitelist
        whiteList: myDefaultWhiteList
    });
});
```